# Suppose that $n\geq1$, find a representation of $G$ over $F$ with degree $n$.

Tags: representation-theory

Suppose that $n\geq1$, find a representation of $G$ over $F$ with degree $n$. 
For which groups $G$ and which values of $n$ is this representation faithful?

So the representation is going to be an $n\times n$ matrix?
But what determines the entries or can they be anything?

I am not sure how to go about this question.
Thanks

Comment: $F$ and $G$ determine the entries.

Comment: See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Group_representation.

Comment: A representation is not a single matrix. The matrices corresponding to each element of $G$ are the data of a representation. The representations are not determined: it's your job to make the representations. You should work on understanding what a representation is.

Comment: @seaturtles okay, yes so the representation is a set of matrices for the elements in G, not a matrix, i should've been clearer, but for the question I am given, what do I do? pick anything? It is going to be a set of nxn matrices isn't it? but besides that I am confused

Comment: The question seems oddly trivial to me. The question already tells you up-front what you need to do: find a representation of $G$ over $F$ with degree $n$. You can just let $G$ act trivially on $F^n$, and this is faithful iff $G$ is trivial (independent of $n$). And that's the end of the question, so perhaps there is more to the problem than I can gather from what you've written. Did you provide a verbatim quote? Is this from a textbook or another source we can view?

Comment: i just am unsure of what it meant to "find", so i could use any example? also, how would I write the example you have given me in terms of matrices?

Comment: Find means provide an example, yes. If you know what the phrase "$G$ act trivially on $F^n$" means you should know what matrices to use...